# Unable to Install Tizen web application on wearable device [Parsing Error -19]

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-emulator, tizen-studio

I'm trying to install Tizen Wearable 5.5 Web Application on my Tizen 4.0 (SM-R800). I'm getting the following popup message:

[image: Installing the package... > Fail Unexpected error occurred at the below step. Installing the package... Please try again later.]

The console shows the following message:

```
Launching the Tizen application...
If you want to see the detailed information,
please set the logging level to DEBUG in Preferences and check the log file in 'C:\tizen-studio-data\ide\logs/ide-20210217_135321.log'.

[Initializing the launch environment...]
    RDS: Off
    Target information: SM-R800
    Application information: Id(Ae1xjFqatt.TAUBasic), Package Name(Ae1xjFqatt), Project Name(TAUBasic)
[Transferring the package...]
    Transferred the package: wgt stream -> /home/owner/share/tmp/sdk_tools/tmp/TAUBasic.wgt
[Installing the package...]
path is /home/owner/share/tmp/sdk_tools/tmp/TAUBasic.wgt
start process (install)

error : -19

end process (fail)
processing result : Parsing error [-19] failed
spend time for pkgcmd is [1529]ms
cmd_ret:237
    An exception occurred
(Installing the package... > Fail)
An exception occurred
Unexpected stop progress...
(15.845 sec)
```

I've taken the following steps so far:

- Created the certificate using Samsung Certificate extension, DUID of device is added in the certificate.
- Selected the `Permit to install applications` option from device, it says there's no need to enable this option for this device.
- Ensured that the SDK Tools are installed.
- Ensured that there are no privileges in the config file which can cause any issue.
- Matched the Time Zone of Device and the Machine.

I've noticed that **I'm also unable to install the app on Emulator 4.0** which means the issue is not related to Certificate. I've read many answers to such queries and applied the solutions but none of them worked for me. I couldn't find any information about the `Parsing error [-19]` related to application installation on device. Previously, I was using Tizen Studio 3.7 and everything was working fine then. I'm facing this issue since I installed Tizen Studio 4.1, therefore I suspect that I might have missed something during the installation of Tizen Studio, which is causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe installation has failed because 
you tried to tizen web application which has build for 
Tizen 5.5 to Tizen 4.0 device or emulator.

I tested with Tizen studio 3.7 with same scenario
(Trying to install Tizen 5.5 application into Tizen 4.0 emulator)
but it failed with same error.